# Share does not showing image

Tags: facebook, image, share

I'm trying to use the facebook share button, but when I use the button to share an URL the image is not displayed on facebook.

Using the facebook debugger the image is displayed correctly, but not at my profile. Can anyone help me with this issue?

(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: Do you have any code? Where did you embed this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Answer (score 1):

your image will not show from localhost until your image has public url to access image, Facebook require public url to show image on share iframe.

Just to check , pick any image url from google and put it hard code into your image path and try once. You will see image.